# Implement simple excel macro into complicated one

Tags: vba, excel

This macro works as it is supposed to do with no conditional filtering on the files.

However I need just to modify this macro so that, it opens each of those files, sorts them from minimum to maximum, **filter for only for those that are above average**, now takes first 100 from these and copies them into new worksheet, making first row of these 100 rows bold.

**Context**

I have 600 excel files (actually extension is `.txt`) in a folder located at filepath `C:\Excel`. This macro opens each of them, sorts them from minimum to maximum, takes first 100 from each and copies them into new worksheet in order as the files are being opened, making each first row of new file bold.

Here is the code:

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    Dim isEmpty As String
    isEmpty = "null"

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "C:\Excel"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    ' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.txt")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
'    With Application
'        CalcMode = .Calculation
'        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'        .ScreenUpdating = False
'        .EnableEvents = False
'    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))

            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next

                    mybook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    mybook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields. _
                    Add Key:=Range("C2:C18000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
                    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

                 ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A2:C101")
                End With



                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    ' If source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If

                On Error GoTo 0
                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.

                       ' With sourceRange
                           ' BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "D").Font.Bold = True
                           ' BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "D"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                       ' End With

                        ' Set the destination range.

                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)



                        With mybook.Worksheets(1).Sort
                                .SetRange Range("A1:C18000")
                                .Header = xlYes
                                .MatchCase = False
                                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                                .Apply
                            End With

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A").Font.Bold = True
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "B").Font.Bold = True
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "C").Font.Bold = True
                            'MsgBox (BaseWks.Cells.Address)
                            If ActiveCell.Text = isEmpty Then
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = 1
                            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
                            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = 0
                            End If
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

The macro is messy but does its job.

**Research**

I managed to find some macros and adopt them, so here is the macro that in active worksheet, filters data for only those that are above average, and takes first 100 and copy them in sheet2 of same workbook.

```
Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C18000").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterAboveAverage, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
   ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows("1:100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

When I try to adopt this macro for my need, I mean to put it after this sort part in "complicated" macro and deleting previous way of copying files, I just cannot make it work.

Also I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101035/macro-to-get-first-100-rows-after-filtering-in-excel) question and got one possible solution for taking first 100 rows of filtered data(I asked this before finding this method here in the "simple macro"), but how to accomplish filtering I still don't get. So I'm asking this question, because I need this ASAP.

P.S. Structure of my files is 3 columns, and each has approximately 18000 rows.

Comment: Isn't waht you're doing more or less the same as just sorting descending and then taking the top 100 rows? I remember you said there were 1000's of rows in each file - what's the chance that the first 100 rows aren't all "above average" ?

Comment: @TimWilliams It's not the same. I need algorithm to take first 100 nearest to the average(both above and below, but here I ask only for above), and this combination: sort in ascending order + filter will give me first 100 above average. Can you help with code? thank you

Comment: Sorry - mis-read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following your existing code but it's honestly kind of a mess (which you've acknowledged).  I re-wrote what I believe you are trying to do.  This does rely on the Scripting Runtime component, so in the VBA window, go to Tools...References... and click on Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Since you are already sorting the data, there's no need for a filter.  Also, you don't specify which column you are sorting on, your code would sort on A so I assumed that.

I did not consider any special cases... i.e. there are more than 18000 rows, there are less than 100 values above the average, etc.  You can probably adapt some of your previous code to handle such situations.

```
Sub StackExample()

Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Scripting.Folder
Dim f As Scripting.File

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsPaste As Excel.Worksheet

Dim avg As Double
Dim r As Long

    Set fo = fso.GetFolder("C:\Excel\")

    For Each f In fo.Files
        If Right(f.Name, 4) = ".txt" Then

            ' assign the variable objects
            Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(fo.Name & f.Name)
            Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
            wb.Worksheets.Add
            Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets(1)
            wsPaste.Move , ws

            ' text to columns (from TXT file)
            ws.Activate
            ws.Range("A1:A18000").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, Comma:=True

            ' sort
            With ws.Sort
                .SetRange Range("A1:C18000")
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlSortColumns
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

            ' calculate the average
            avg = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws.Range("A2:A18000"))

            ' find the first row with a value equal to or greater than the average
            For r = 2 To 18000
                If ws.Cells(r, 1).Value >= avg Then Exit For
            Next r

            ' copy the range, then paste
            ws.Range(ws.Cells(r, 1), ws.Cells(r + 99, 3)).Copy
            wsPaste.Activate
            wsPaste.Paste wsPaste.Range("A1")

            ' save and close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.SaveAs Left(f.Name, Len(f.Name) - 4), xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            wb.Close
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        End If
    Next f

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I think you have solved my problem :) just it gives me error when I try to run this macro. Here's the PrntScrn http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/19/stackproblem.png/ Am I missing something?

Comment: should be ... Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(fo.Name & f.Name).  I have edited it.